# I don't know why i can't use scanf_s()?

Tags: c

I have homework in my C programming class.
I have to input 3 people's information about name, major, ID(ex. 9304171)and output to console
'name, birth(yyyy-mm-dd), leep year, nationality, sex, major'.

I tried to that, but my scanf_s wasn't activated.
if i try to activate to my code, char array can activated, but my integer array can't activated.

```
char name[4]; // name
char major[4]; // major
int id[7] = {}; // ID

// Input name, major, ID 

printf("Name : ");
scanf_s("%s \n", &name, 4);

printf("Major : ");
scanf_s(" %s \n", &department, 4);

printf("ID : ");
scanf_s("%d \n", id);
```

My English ability is so fool... but it is make me so angry, i begging to help..

plz, sombody help me T.T

Comment: Do you need to accept values specifically with `scanf_s()`?

Comment: 3 characters is a bit short for someone's name, or their major. Also please change `scanf_s("%s \n", &name, 4);` to `scanf_s("%s", name, 4);` and change `scanf_s(" %s \n", &department, 4);` to `scanf_s("%s", major, 4);`

Comment: Also please change `int id[7] = {};` to `char id[8];` and input in the same way as the others.

Comment: You have defined `id` as an array of 7 integers, but you likely only need a single integer, like this: `int id;` and then change your scanf_s call to `scanf_s("%d", &id)`, or alternatively treat the id as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Declare something like:

```
char name[50], major[50];
int id; // array removed
```

You can use `fgets()` if you're having issues with `scanf_s()`, I suspect you've given such short number of elements for name array (i.e. 4) and that's something relatable with the error. Try the following using `fgets()`:

```
printf("Name: ");
fgets(name, 50, stdin); // fgets buffered for 50 elements

printf("Major: ");
fgets(major, 50, stdin); // fgets ...

printf("ID: ");
scanf("%d", &id); // scanf() can be used here
```

Let's take a look at a sample output (no errors):

```
// INPUT
Name: John Doe
Major: Something
ID: 101

// OUTPUT
Name: John Doe
Major: Something
ID: 101
```